# JList won't add data to it

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist, filelist

If i want to add an `ArrayList` to a `JList`, it is not shown in the list, but the array contains the items. How could i fix this?

```
  public void updateLeftList(){
        // Enter the search text
        interFace.Search.setText(this.search);

        // Get the left list
        JList leftList = interFace.LeftList;
        leftList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        // Define the arraylists
        allPdf = new ArrayList();
        curPdf = new ArrayList();
        addPdf = new ArrayList();

        // Get Files from manuals folder        
        File files = new File(configFile.getProperty("dir") + "/" + this.taal);
        File[] listFiles = files.listFiles();

        for(int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++){
            if(listFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".pdf") && listFiles[i].isFile()){
                allPdf.add(listFiles[i].getName().toString());
            }
        }
        leftList.setListData(allPdf.toArray());
    }
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, otherwise this question isn't answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ListModel to add the data:
1. create new instance of `DefaultListModel`
2. add your file names to the list model
3. set it as your `JList` list model

Comment: My `InterFace` class is not working. In the Construstor i call `interFace = new InterFace()`. But this is not working if i call the method `updateLeftList()` in another class

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Are there any exceptions? It is hard to give some advice without seeing relevant fragments of code...

Comment: There are no exceptions. `InterFace` is made with the NetBeans Design Editor. `Manuals` is the main class and in it's constructor i call `interFace = new InterFace()`. Also `updateLeftList` is defined in `Manuals` class. The problem occurs when i call `updateLeftList` from class `NewProject` which is made with NetBeans Design Editor

Comment: I would try to make a break in updateLeftList() and go through it step by step to see, where it goes south. Do I understand it correctly, that if you call updateLeftList() from another project, it does not update your JList even when using DefaultListModel? It is a longshot from the belt, but problem could also be that you should call it on event dispatch thread... it is a general advice, I have almost no experience with NetBeans

Comment: Found the problem, i create a new object of InterFace. But how do i pass the main interface to the new windows called newproject

Comment: Got it! Thanks for helping! I didnt pass the interface object to next window

Comment: you're welcome, I am glad you've found it, looks like I didn't have to help you at all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Object item : arrayList.toArray()){
    ((DefaultListModel) list1.getModel()).addElement(item);
}
```